# How to remove a pattern from each line in a text file in Python

Tags: python

I have a file that consists of data shown below

```
 GS*642510*18762293*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*HN*056000522*601200162*20210513*101046*200018825*X*005010X214
 ST*642510*18762293*1*0*0*0*0*0*0*277*000000001*005010X214
 BHT*642510*18762293*1*0*0*0*0*0*0*0085*08*1*20210513*101046*TH
 NM1*642510*18762293*1*1*1*1*1*0*0*QC*1*TORIBIO QUEZADA*YERINSON****MI*1000836598
 NM1*642510*18762293*1*1*1*4*1*0*0*QC*1*DELACRUZ*JENNIFER*L***MI*1000232209
```

I want to delete the data from the 1st * till the 9th *
I have written some code in python but not sure how to use regular expression as the string itself contains a "*" itself.
My PY Code is

```
import os
import re

path2 = "C:/Users/Lsaxena2/Desktop/RI Stuff/RI RITM1456876 Response files/Processed files with 
no Logs"
files = os.listdir(path2)
print(files)
for x in files:
   with open(path2+'/'+x,'r') as f:
        newText = f.read().replace("*446607*12004230*","*")
   with open(path2+'/'+x,'w') as f:
        f.write(newText)
```

After update the data should looks like

```
 GS*HN*056000522*601200162*20210513*101046*200018825*X*005010X214
 ST*277*000000001*005010X214
 BHT*0085*08*1*20210513*101046*TH
 NM1*QC*1*TORIBIO QUEZADA*YERINSON****MI*1000836598
 NM1*QC*1*DELACRUZ*JENNIFER*L***MI*1000232209
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a regular expression to solve this, but if you know that you always want to remove the content between the first and ninth stars, then I would split your strings into lists by "*" and rejoin select slices. For example:

```py
mystring = "GS*642510*18762293*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*HN*056000522*601200162*20210513*101046*200018825*X*005010X214"

split_string = mystring.split("*")
# ['GS', '642510', '18762293', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'HN', '056000522', '601200162', '20210513', '101046', '200018825', 'X', '005010X214']
desired_slices = split_string[:1] + split_string[10:]
pruned_string = "*".join(desired_slices)
pruned_string
# 'GS*HN*056000522*601200162*20210513*101046*200018825*X*005010X214'
```

Answer (score 2):

https://regex101.com/r/khgAVj/1

[image]

regex pattern: `(\*\w+){9}\*`

Explanation of the regex pattern can be found on the regex101 page on the right side.
There is a code generator and replacing/removing the section should be fairly trivial. StackOverflow isn't a place that writes code for you. It helps you at debugging the code. So I will not give a finished solution but merely point you in the direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/oK0eO2/2)

```
/\*(.*?\*){9}/g
```

You did not mention in the question that you want only the first occurrence of this pattern in a line. If you are using regex this, or the accepted one, be sure to only take the first match in a line.

In case if the pattern repeats in the same line, I think you don't want to replace that.

[image: Accepted Answer Matchs]

As you can see both my suggestion and the accepted answer will match every pattern even if it re occurs in the same line.
It will be better if you use the Answer suggested by [Bruce Schultz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13011577/bruce-schultz)